# Creating github repository for organisation assign maintainer admin rights only to the creator

Tags: github

We are group of developers who have a joint organisation on GitHub.
When we create a repository for the organisation on GitHub it is only the creator that is made admin and read, write, and maintainance rights are not given to the organisation, nor the organisation team.
We have to go to Settings => Manage Access every time.
Can this somehow be changed?

We have already contact GitHub support but after 3 months and no answer, we believe it is okay to ask the question here.

Comment: You can create a team for the developers and give the team the required permission per-repository. You can also give the developers admin permissions on your organisation what also gives them admin permissions for every repository.

Comment: But why is it needed for each repo, when it is owned by the organisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in the organisation settings under `Member privileges`. The option is named `Base permissions`.

[image]

You can also access it under `https://github.com/organizations/<organisation name>/settings/member_privileges`.

By default, organisation members have no permissions in repositories created by other organisation members. In this setting, you can configure the permissions every member has in every repository owned by the organisation.

You can also create a team for the developers and give the team the required permission per-repository.